# Asp.net Login Control, render only the server side controls without the HTML

Tags: asp.net, login-control

The Login Control does not render the html under the layout template,it render only the server side controls,
this is the markup:

```
<asp:Login ID="Login11" EnableTheming="false" runat="server" MembershipProvider="SqlProvider"
            OnLoginError="Login11_LoginError" LoginButtonType="Link">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div class="login-box">
                    <div>
                        <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    User name:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Password:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="<%=Util.BaseUrl %>Pages/Account/ForgotPassword.aspx">Forgot Password?</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" Text="Remember my password"></asp:CheckBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LoginBtn" CommandName="Login" runat="server" CssClass="login-btn">Login</asp:LinkButton>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:Login>
```

**And the output is :**

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login11$Password" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login11_Password" type="password">

<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login11_RememberMe" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login11$RememberMe" type="checkbox">

<label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login11_RememberMe">Remember my password</label>

<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login11_LoginBtn" class="login-btn" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login11$LoginBtn','')">Login</a>
```

Why this Happen ?!

Comment: if you set to `true` the property `EnableTheming` what will happen?

Comment: seams that you are missing some configuration, I just tried with a simple webform page and works normally...

Comment: Yes it must run, but i cant configure what is missing

Comment: Is your Login control inside a form tag with runat="server"?

Comment: @slfan yes,its inside a contentHolder which runat server

Comment: Thank you all, I Solved the Problem , The problem is I Used a server tag inside the LayoutTemlate `<%=Util.BaseUrl %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the following:

```
<%=Util.BaseUrl %>
```

from the HTML tag

```
<a href="<%=Util.BaseUrl %>Pages/Account/ForgotPassword.aspx">Forgot Password?</a>
```

the layout template has rendered correclty.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I was going almost crazy or something. Until I saw your question. Then I though, I am not the only one to stumble upon this bug.

I don't know why is this happening, but your question includes the solution (or better, the workaround)

I see you have a div there (`class="login-box"`) at the top of the hierarchy. I suppose setting the runat attribute (`runat="server"`) will solve the problem.

At least that is what I did, except I had a table, not a div at the top of my hierarchy. Making the table run at the server side (meaning there is actually an `HtmlTable` control added to the template's Controls collection), fixed the problem, and I didn't need to set any other client side elements below this table, to run at server side. Only the top element needed the runat attribute.